# Background Image starts repeating when Screen height is changed

Tags: ios, iphone-4

My background image is `320*436`.
It's working perfectly on iPhone4 but when I run on iPhone5 the background starts repeating.

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

How do I make this compatible with iPhone5?

Comment: Make an imageview with image "bg.png", set its frame to self.view.frame and add subview in self.view Make sure imageview is at index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write at beginning if ViewDidLoad if not using xib. if using xib drag and drop a full screen imageview at 0 index of UIView. Set image to it. Set autoresizemask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

```
UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will happen because you are setting backgroundColor and colorWithPatternImage.You can set imageView on the top of your background and set image on it , or try to use bigger image for the background that will fit iPhone 5 and will be smaller on 4